# Create CGI Custom Server variable in Coldfusion 2018

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2018

I'm using Coldfusion Builder 2018 and running a coldfusion application in local. This application was protected with SSO and the server is setting CGI variables in Dev/Prod. I want to override this CGI variable in my local server to run the application.

Can someone help me on how to override the CGI variable in local?

Comment: Can you provide some examples of what you are trying? Which webserver are you using?

Comment: I'm using CF Server(Tomcat?) in local.
<cfset SESSION.USERID = CGI.HTTP_USERID>

Comment: You can't overwrite CGI.HTTP_HOST values. It's refer from the URL / host value only. Even you can't manually update it. If you have local set up properly. It will have your local host value by default.

Comment: Are you really using `CGI.HTTP_USERID`?  I don't think that is a CGI variable. I know of `CGI.REMOTE_USER` or `CGI.AUTH_USER`. Did you try those?

Comment: @Miguel-F That's a custom CGI variable set by the SSO process. It's not a default CF supplied value.

Comment: Could you check for the existence of the variable?  `<cfset session.userid = ? StructKeyExists(cgi.http_userid) cgi.http_userid : "something else">`

Comment: I'm perhaps re-task this as a Tomcat question, rather than a CF one.  You're more likely to get a useful response from the Tomcat crowd than the CF one. You want to ask how to set bespoke CGI variables in Tomcat. I expect CF will just take whatever it's given, and expose them all in the CGI scope.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to create your own abstraction instead. So create a function / CFC that you get your variables from. Depending on environment you can get these from configuration (or something else), and in prod you can honour the CGI variables. I am not sure you can override CGI variables.